# Constructing a .htaccess file to hide a string in certain cases

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'd like to be able to hide a $_REQUEST variable name in a visitor's address bar, and also automatically append the variable name to all data requests, but only when the .php extension is not included.

**Currently requests look like this:**

> example.com/?page=request

**I'd like them to look like this**

> example.com/request

**The problem is, domains like this still need to work:**

> example.com/mail.php

**So I figure I'd like all requests to files that don't end in the extension .php to invisibly forward to the contents of**

> example.com/?page=*

**While actually displaying the address:**

> example.com/*

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=-
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R]
```

But this doesn't even replace the string when it's entered.

I wouldn't mind actually having to add the name of each accessible .php file to the .htaccess file, this would probably build on security.

Comment: Your current and desired examples are exactly the same, are they not?

Comment: That must be a typo @DanFarrell, Whoops! :P Sorry haha

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to forward `/request` URI to `/?page=request`. If thats the case use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^].]+)$ /?page=$1? [L,QSA]
```